# How Add select box Dynamically, which retrieve data from Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have problem with Web Development,
i have added drop down list using PHP, MySQL and HTML. Now i want to use button and dynamically generate same Select box again and again. How can i do this, please help me..
Here is my Select Box Code.

```
 <Select name="txt-computer_sn" class="form-control" id="txt-computer_sn">
     <?php
         include ('../svr/connection.php');
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM supplier";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             echo '<option value=' . $row['supplier_id'] . '>' . $row['supplier_name'] . '</option>';
         }
     ?>                         
 </select>
```

Comment: will the data of dropdown remain same when it generates again and again or it will also be change every time?

Answer (score 0):

if the data of dropdown will remain same then you can do that in this way

html and php

```
<Select name="txt-computer_sn" class="form-control dynm_drop" id="txt-computer_sn">
                                    <?php
                                    include ('../svr/connection.php');
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM supplier";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo '<option value=' . $row['supplier_id'] . '>' . $row['supplier_name'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>                         
                                </select>
```

jquery

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
  $(".dynm_drop").clone().appendTo("class or id of element");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="select_wrapper">
    <select name="txt-computer_sn[0]" class="form-control" id="txt-computer_sn_0">
        <?php
        include ('../svr/connection.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM supplier";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value=' . $row['supplier_id'] . '>' . $row['supplier_name'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>                         
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="add_select" class="add_select" value="Add New">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s=1;
  $('.add_select').click(function(e){ //Once add button is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    s++;
    $('.select_wrapper').append('<select class="form-control" name="txt-computer_sn['+s+']" id="txt-computer_sn_'+s+'">'+$('#txt-computer_sn_0').html()+'</select>');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is 3 method to do this.i am not familiar with php.but i tell the method how to work it out.
1.you have to set an hidden field for count
2.
`<select class="form-control" name="txt-computer_sn--" id="txt-computer_sn_--">`

3.in the script write this var rep=/--/gi;
4. take your count from hidden field

```
var Count= $("#Count").val()
Count =++Count                                
("#div1").append($("#div2").html().replace(rep,Count));
```

5. on click the add button you have append the div2 with select to another
   div1
6. on remove the
   `$("#div3"+id).remove()`
7. in the order
   `<div1></div>
        <div2 id="name1--"style=display:none>
   <div3 id="name2--"></div3>
   </div2>`

it will work.use this concept .you can do this in  php also..